# Can i create a file in databases directory?

Tags: android

i need to create, at runtime, a database file in the databases directory (/data/data/pkg-name/databases/). My question is: is it possible?

If i try to create it with:

```
File unzipped = new File(context.getDatabasePath(filename + ".db").getPath());
unzipped.createNewFile();
```

the app goes in error with: ...no such file or directory...

Some idea how i can do this?

> i download from internet the database that i need to create, this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Some idea how i can do this?

Create the directory. Android will not create the directory automatically until you try creating your first database with `SQLiteDatabase` or `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if:

1. Directory exists, if not create it.
2. File exists, if not create it.

But if you re actually trying to create a sqlite database there are better ways of doing that

```
private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        OpenHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME
                + "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        while (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            Log.w("Example",
                    "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
            if (oldVersion == 4) {
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+ " ADD COLUMN type INTEGER");

            }
            else if(oldVersion>=5)
            {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
                onCreate(db);
            }
            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
}
```